# Remote desktop on Windows 2012 R2 doesn't work

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I have 5 machines on remote server with Windows server 2012 installed on.

Usually, I access on these machines using remote desktop connection.

This morning I've accessed on one of these 5 machines without trouble, but on the others four I can't access.

Remains on video the starting console with progress bar but doesn't happen anything. No error messages show on my PC.

I've tried also with command line:

```
mstsc /admin
```

but nothing, the result is the same

[image: I attach the image on my PC.]

Comment: Can you ping all 5 hosts? Is this 1 physical with 5 VMs or 5 physical machines?

Comment: Ping is OK. 5 are virtual machine. On one of these, there's Sql Server and I access from my PC on Management Studio. Only remote desktop doesn't work

Comment: What mode are the VMs using to access the local network?

Comment: Ok! My collegue has disabled and re-enable a rule of PFSense Firewall and now it's OK.